# Unit of measurement for constant K

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I have the question "A baby of mass 9.0kg bounces with a period of 1.2s in a baby bouncer. What is the spring constant of the bouncer."

For this I rearranged the formula for period to make K the subject. The final answer I get is K = 246.74.

However, I am not sure what the units should be for the constant k.

Comment: Assuming a damping constant of $0$?

Comment: The spring constant is force divided by distance, so working with Kg, Newtons and meters it would be Newtons/meter.